# The Mathematica Entropy[] Function

Tags: information-function

1). Does it use the Shannon Entropy function? (Not specified in
documentation)

2). Does it work on 3D arrays? (Seems to).

3). What are its Min (assume 0) and Max values? (Not specified in
documentation).

Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 3):

```
list = RandomChoice[{a, b, c}, 1000];

tallies = Tally[list]

(* {{b, 316}, {c, 331}, {a, 353}} *)
```

Base E (default)

```
Entropy[list] == -Total[#*Log[#] & /@ (tallies[[All, 2]]/Length[list])]

(* True *)
```

Base 2

```
Entropy[2, list] == -Total[#*Log2[#] & /@ (tallies[[All, 2]]/Length[list])]

(* True *)
```

Base 10

```
Entropy[10, list] == -Total[#*Log10[#] & /@ (tallies[[All, 2]]/Length[list])]

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** The entropy is maximized when all of the choices are equally likely. For `n` equally likely choices, the entropy is `Log[n]/Log[b]` where `b` is the base.

Comment: Log[Exp[1]] == 1 so why divide by Ln[e]?

Comment: `Log[n]/Log[b]` is the result for an arbitrary positive base. For `b == E` it does simplify to `Log[n]`.